# Restricting character input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm really curious as how to restrict character input in a program like a calculator can anyone teach me how to do it, I'm really new to this. And if someone answers could you please explain every line of code in your answer. Thanks in advance. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    double add, sub, mul, div, rem, square, power, v1, v2;
    long double sine, cosine, tangent;  
    do{
        cout << "Choose an operation." << endl << "\n";
        cout << "[1] Addition." << endl;
        cout << "[2] Subtraction." << endl;
        cout << "[3] Multiplication." << endl;
        cout << "[4] Division." << endl;
        cout << "[5] Exit." << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 5){
        cout << "Please Choose from 1 to 5" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
    }
if (choice == 1){
    cout << "Please Enter 1st value: ";
    cin >> v1;

    cout << "Please Enter 2nd value: ";
    cin >> v2;

    add = v1 + v2;
    cout << "The answer is: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << add << endl << endl;   
}
else if (choice == 2){
    cout << "Please Enter 1st value: ";
    cin >> v1;

    cout << "Please Enter 2nd value: ";
    cin >> v2;

    sub = v1 - v2;
    cout << "The answer is: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << sub << endl << endl;
}
if (choice == 3){
    cout << "Please Enter 1st value: ";
    cin >> v1;

    cout << "Please Enter 2nd value: ";
    cin >> v2;

    mul = v1 * v2;

    cout << "The answer is: " << fixed << setprecision(2) <<  mul << endl << endl;
}
if (choice == 4){
    cout << "Please Enter 1st value: ";
    cin >> v1;

    cout << "Please Enter 2nd value: ";
    cin >> v2;

    div = v1 / v2;
    rem = fmod (v1,v2);

    cout << "The answer is: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << div << " remainder " << rem << endl << endl;
}
if (choice == 5)
    break;  
}
while (choice != 5);
{
    cout << endl << "Goodbye.";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Do you ask for common ways to write validators for a given grammar? If you just want to restrict your set of input characters you can easily check every input for that. Otherwise my best guess would be [boost.spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

Comment: You probably want to use `cin.get()` and read a single character at time so that you can check for its validity

Comment: Is it possible that you would like to prevent the user from "inputting" a non-number in the first place; for example, if the user presses the key "A" nothing (or an error message) should appear? If that guess is correct I must disappoint you as far as standard C++ and the Windows Console or a Linux terminal goes. Both environments (OS plus command processor plus text window) send whole lines in single chunks to the program by default, so that the program cannot prevent "wrong" input. Both environments *can* let a program see each key stroke, but the methods are proprietary and non-portable.

Comment: ... (That's the catch with @Emiliano 's suggestion: Yes, with `cin.get()` the program can check each character for validity but can't do anything about it because the character is part of a whole  line of  input already "entered".)

Answer (score 1):

Check [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) of the functions you are using.

Simplified code:

```
double v1;
std::cin >> v1;
```

This is attempting to extract a `double` from `std::cin`, skipping leading whitespace.

If extraction fails -- e.g. because somebody entered something that isn't a representation of a `double` value -- a zero is written (since C++11, previously the value was left unchanged), **and the [failbit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) set on the stream**.

This can be checked, and cleared:

```
if ( std::cin.fail() )
{
    // handle error
    std::cin.clear();
}
```

Actually the page on [clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) has a fully functional example of reading a number, checking for failure, and repeating the input.

That being said, I second @Maikel's comment. If you want to take this beyond the experimentation stage, you will want to write a true grammar parser, for which [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) is a strong choice.